# Vertically centering equations next to images?

Tags: graphics, equations, minipage

So I am trying to put equations next to graphics using the `minipage` environment, but the equations won't vertically center within the environment to match the picture. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{parallelplates}
  \captionof{figure}{A diagram showing the uniform electric field between two parallel capacitor plates. placeholder citation}
  \label{fig:parallelplates}
\end{minipage}%
\hfil
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{equation}
C=Q\Delta V
  \label{eq:capacitance}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  \frac{1}{C_T}=\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{C_n}
  \label{eq:capseries}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
  C_T=C_1+C_2+\cdots + C_n
  \label{eq:capparallel}
  \end{equation}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks! Here is an image!

[image: 1]

Comment: Do you want to center with image or its caption? Also, the image is too wide. Use `\usepackage{showframe}` to see the margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}  % inserted
\usepackage{showframe}% just to exemplify
\begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\textwidth}% changed to c
            \centering
            % I changed the image width
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \captionof{figure}{A diagram showing the uniform electric field between two parallel capacitor plates. placeholder citation}
            \label{fig:parallelplates}
        \end{minipage}%
        \hfil
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.45\textwidth}% changed to c
            \centering
            \begin{equation}
            C=Q\Delta V
            \label{eq:capacitance}
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
            \frac{1}{C_T}=\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{C_n}
            \label{eq:capseries}
            \end{equation}
            \begin{equation}
            C_T=C_1+C_2+\cdots + C_n
            \label{eq:capparallel}
            \end{equation}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

% another option

\noindent%
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{A diagram showing the uniform electric field between two parallel capacitor plates. placeholder citation}
    \label{fig:parallelplates}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.49\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{equation}
    C=Q\Delta V
    \label{eq:capacitance}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{C_T}=\frac{1}{C_1}+\frac{1}{C_2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{C_n}
    \label{eq:capseries}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    C_T=C_1+C_2+\cdots + C_n
    \label{eq:capparallel}
    \end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]